# Spring Security / Application to Application / JWT bearer

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I am working on securise the "WebFlux" endpoints of my application using Spring Security 5.1.1.RELEASE. What I would like to achieve is the following scenario :

- **Authentication Server** : I am using Keycloak as an authentication server
- **Resource server** : I am using `spring-security-oauth2-resource-server` package to provide JWT authentication on specific paths
- **Client** : I need to use an OAuth2 authentication based on "client credentials"

When I am using curl, it is pretty easy :

- Request a new token from my authentication server using "token" endpoint and "client_credentials" grant type
- Extract the "access_token" from the JSON answer
- Use the JWT in the `-H "Authorization: Bearer $JWT"` option of curl to embed the token in my request

Now, I want to Spring injections in order to use a `WebClient` bean configured to request automatically the JWT token and then use it to access the securised endpoint of my application.

I have tried to implement the example shown in the documentation [Spring Security - WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#webclient) but with no success.

I am looking for Application to Application authentication example. One is the Resource Server and the other one is the Client, connecting to the WebFlux API with a WebClient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to perform an implementation of a OAuth2 authentication process using Spring Security OAuth2 libs (client and resource-server) for a machine-to-machine scenario.

Please find the demo sources and some explanation at this link : https://github.com/Brico87/spring-security-oauth2-m2m.

Spring Security with OAuth2 support is quite quick and efficient to use if you manage to find the good combination between the components instanciation !